# My website doesn't send the mail even though it works perfectly on wamp

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Here is my website: www.accurateaccountsinc.tk
The problem is that the website just loads and doesn't do anything.
Everything works properly in localhost/wamp but it doesn't work on the actual site when running the task.

here's the code for the form

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="text" required name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
    <input type="text" required name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" />
    <input type="text" required name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
    <textarea name="message" required id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="mailed" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's the php:

```
<?php 
    include 'dbconn.php';
    if(isset($_POST['mailed'])){
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
        $emailadd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
        $contact = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['phone']);
        $entrymessage = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['message']);

        include "class.phpmailer.php";
        include "class.smtp.php";
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMPTDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Username = "email here";
        $mail->Password = "password here";
        $mail->SetFrom("email here", 'Website Entry');
        $subject = "Client Entry";
        $message = "<br>Client Name: " . $name;
        $message .= "<br>Email Address: " . $emailadd;
        $message .= "<br>Contact Number: " . $contact;
        $message .= "<br>Message: " . $entrymessage;
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message;
        $mail->AddAddress("email here", $name);

        if($mail->Send()){
            unset($_POST['mailed']);
            echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

if there's any more info you'd like to know please do ask..
also note that I only used the class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php to minimize the work needed if that's related to the problem..

Comment: If the code works fine in your localhost then it probably means your server/host is blocking port 587. Try to confirm it.

Comment: Or the included files are located in a different location. `mysqli_real_escape_string` is for DB escaping, won't do anything for data in the email.

Comment: Is there a way to unblock that port? or any workaround?

Comment: Unblocking port is from your server configuration. You can use other port. Gmail also provide Port 25 (remove SMTPSecure = 'tls'), and Port 465 (change SMTPSecure = 'ssl')

Comment: I'll try that thanks!

Comment: Tried both it did not work unfortunately

Comment: Ask your server admin whether these ports are open. These ports are normally blocked if the server provider has it's own email service.

Answer (score 1):

Typo: `$mail->SMPTDebug` should be `$mail->SMTPDebug`, and you should set it to `2` for useful feedback.

You're also not displaying any errors that it may have caused, so `echo $mail->ErrorInfo;` if sending fails.

You can't send *through* gmail on port 25, only *to* gmail. Stick to `tls` on Port 587, like all the examples and [docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki) say. I don't know where you got your code, but it looks like you used an old example - you should base it on [the examples provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples), particularly the ones for gmail.